# UISearchaBar is disappearing from UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I've a view controller (named it as **SearchViewController**) with UITableView and UISearchBar. UISearchBar is set to table as a **header view**. While searching in the table using this searchbar works great.

By selecting any one of the displayed search results, I can move to next view (named it as **DetailsViewController**). But after returning to the **SearchViewController**, magically the **UISearchBar** is disappeared and my app is crashed. I found the same code is working fine on iOS 3.1.2 but not on iOS 4.0 (no idea about 4.0.1 or 4.0.2).

I'll be really thankful, if anyone has a work around for this.

Comment: Found this is a bug in iPhone SDK 4.0. To avoid this problem, in my SearchViewController's "viewDidDisappear" I added this line,

myTbView.tableHeaderView = mySerachBar; Thats it problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I always use an UINavigationBar and an UINavigationItem to display the UISearchBar. Setting the navigationItem.titleView to the searchBar works fine for me. (Don't forget to call `[theSearchBar sizeToFit]`)

Please give us more information on the crash. What is the console output?

Comment: Felix, thanks for quick response. As par my requirements I can’t use SearchBar with navigation controller. Well it seems a bug in the iPhone SDK 4.0. 

The crash report always says there is a problem in UIKit (not remember whats the problem is), not related to my view classes. I’m planning to use UISearchDisplayController instead of UISearchBar.